# How to use a typesetting content to send mail on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, email, cat

I want to send a mail which includes a table on linux.
To type cat command, the content as below:

[image]

But when I use `cat $REPORT | mail -s "$MAIL_TITLE" $MAIL_TO`
The content in the mail will be as below:

[image: [2]]

Is it possible to fix that?  Thx

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal is using `monospace` font that has same width of each character including spaces.

To make your email looks same way you need to

- define the content font to use one of the monospace fonts

or

- switch your email client to use the monospace font as default.

[Monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

**Edit**

To your example you may just wrap the output into the `<div style="font-family: monospace;">...</div>` that will force it to be using the monospace and the formatting will looks much better

**Possible solution**

Is to prepare the output using html div with monospace font family, so the email client will use any kind of monospace that is available in its environment:

```
echo "<div style='font-family: monospace;'>\n" > monospacemail.txt 
echo $REPORT >> monospacemail.txt 
echo '</div>'  >> monospacemail.txt 
cat monospacemail.txt | mail -s "$MAIL_TITLE"' $MAIL_TO
```

Comment: So that's mean I need to change the txt file to html to be the mail content?

Comment: @wilson I have updated my answer with an example. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on linux. Do I need to install some libraries to use html format? After I use this solution, the div command don't work

Comment: No, there is no need to install any html libraries. Try this one line command to your shell:
`echo "<div style='font-family: monospace;'>" > monospacemail.txt ; df -h | head >> monospacemail.txt ; echo '</div>'  >> monospacemail.txt ; cat monospacemail.txt | mail -s 'hello world' email@domain.ext` 
Change the email address at the end of course. Does it works for you?

Comment: Dear ino,
the same result. Still not work lol

Comment: The mail content just showed your div command. The command doesn't work

Comment: @Wilson What do you mean with `div command`? Any part of the output is missing? What email client do you use?

Comment: The mail content will show : <div style='font-family: monospace;'> which you want me to add to the content.
But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
REPORT_FILE_HTML=/tmp/mail.html
MAIL_SUBJECT="some fixed type content"
MAIL_TO=me@home.com

# mail output of vnstat-command: terminal table
echo "<html><pre>" >$REPORT_FILE_HTML
vnstat -m >>$REPORT_FILE_HTML
echo '</pre></html>'  >>$REPORT_FILE_HTML

cat $REPORT_FILE_HTML | mail \
   --append="Content-Type: text/html" \
   --content-filename=$REPORT_FILE_HTML \
   --subject="$MAIL_SUBJECT" $MAIL_TO
```